# A weaker power mean than in Smale's mean value conjecture, but a neat result

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

EDIT: I am a fool, something stronger is true and I should have seen it immediately from my own proof. For any critical point which is not a zero itself we have:

$$ P_{-2}(\ldots) \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{n-M}{n} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{M}{n \, x_{k,l+1}}}} \ \leq \ P_{-1}(\ldots) \ \leq \ \frac{n - M}{n} \, . $$

Here, the dots refer to the contents of the brackets in inequality (*) and $x_{k,l+1}$ is the entry of the so-called augmented Gauss-Lucas matrix corresponding to the zero at the origin and the critical point $z'_k$ under consideration. In this inequality there is equality on the left, if and only if all $ |z_j - z'_k|/|z_j| \, , \, j \leq n - M $ are equal and there is equality on the right, if and only if all zeros lie on a straight line and the origin and the critical point under consideration are not contained in the convex hull of the other zeros.

In our notation, we have

$$ x_{k,l+1} \ = \ \frac{M}{n} \, \frac{P_{-1}(|z_j - z'_k|^2 , j \leq n)}{|z'_k|^2} \ \left(  \leq \ \frac{n - M}{n}  \right) \, . $$

Here, the inequality on the right is an equality if and only if there are only two distinct zeros.

The questions remain the same as below.

End of Edit.

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with a simple zero at the origin. Smale's mean value conjecture from 1981 can be stated as the existence of a critical point $z'_k$, so $p'(z'_k) \, = \, 0$, of $p(z)$, such that

$$ \prod^{n-1}_{j = 1} \frac{|z_j - z'_k|}{|z_j|} \ \leq \ K \, . $$

Here, $z_j$ are the zeros of $p(z)$ distinct from 0 and $K$ is assumed to be 1 or $(n-1)/n$, but can not be smaller in general, due to examples like $p(z) \, = \, z^n - z$. Smale's conjecture can therefore be seen as a statement, that a critical point of $p$ exists, such that the n-1st power of the geometric mean, the power mean of order 0, of the numbers in the inequality above fulfills it.

If M is the multiplicity of the zero of $p$ at the the origin and $P_{-2}$ is the power mean of order -2, I think I can prove

$$ P_{-2} \left( \frac{|z_j - z'_k|}{|z_j|}; j \, \leq \, n - M \right) \ \leq \ \frac{n - M}{n} \quad (*)$$

for **all** critical points of $p$, where equality applies if and only if $p$ has only two distinct zeros, hence the title. This is certainly weaker than the conjecture, while the prove consists only of some elementary calculations involving the standard inequality for the power means and is rather short.

Unfortunately, I am an amateur and therefore can not easily check the current state of the art, so I have some questions:

**1. Is the result $(*)$ of interest at all? Is it worth bothering a referee, for instance?**

**2. Is this known or the conjecture resolved? Can someone provide corresponding references?**

What I have managed to do: Checked Smale's article from 1981, checked the corresponding chapter in Rahman and Schmeisser from 2002, checked all the references I managed to find on the internet. The latest I could read was from 2012. While the connection to the geometric mean was stated, I found no one to bother with other power means. I asked this in a more detailed way on MSE months ago in a question which is not up to date, receiving no feedback:

[Corresponding old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433720/part-ii-of-tiny-results-in-polynomial-geometry-i-would-like-to-have)